# Difficulty with a program that prints out the number of days between two separate years selected by the user

Tags: c, loops

I'm in an intro to C class, and my professor just moved us from python (as an introduction) to C. I'm having a bit of difficulty getting the C syntax down. The program is supposed to calculate the number of days between two separate years and account for leap years.

This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int startyear, endyear;
    int totalyears, index;
    int difference, numyears, days;

    printf("What is the starting year of your time period?\n");
    scanf("%d", &startyear);
    printf("What is the ending year of your time period?\n");
    scanf("%d", &endyear);

    difference = startyear;
    numyears = 0;
    days = 0;

    while (difference <= endyear) {
        difference++;
        numyears++;
        if (difference / 4 == 1) {
            days + 1;

        }
     }

    printf("There are %d days between 1/1/%d and 1/1/%d\n", days + numyears * 365 ,     startyear, endyear);

return 0;
```

}

When I use 2003 and 2005 as the two years, but the program prints out the result as 4,201,453 days, which is clearly wrong. The actual result should be about 731. I know I've probably made a few errors in my while loop, but I'm not quite sure how to fix it. I'm trying to make sure that the while loop checks to see if the month is divisible by 4, which would mark a leap year, and I assumed that in order to do this, I'd use the line:

```
if (difference / 4 == 1) {
        days + 1;
```

The "1" meaning to return the boolean expression as "true," but I'm not quite sure if that's how C reads it. I apologize for the long question, but I'm just trying to be as clear as possible. I also apologize because I feel like I'm posting a mess of code, but I really have no idea where to go from here in order to fix this.

Thanks in advance, guys and gals.

**EDIT: I've followed the comments so far, and I've managed to get the program to calculate 1095 days. I'm getting closer, but there must still be something off in my calculations.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your main loop:

```
while (difference <= endyear) {
```

This will run too many times.  Use `<` instead of `<=`.

```
        difference++;
        numyears++;
```

This means the first year you examine will be `startyear+1` and the last (after fixing above) will be `endyear`.  This isn't quite what you want, so move these increments after the `if` statement (actually only the `difference++;` matters, but for clarity moving both makes sense).

```
        if (difference / 4 == 1) {
```

Now that we're looking at the correct years (from above), you should be checking against `0`.  Also, you're looking for the modulus operator (`%`), not division.  Thus, we have `difference % 4 == 0`.

```
            days + 1;
```

This doesn't have any effects.  You want either `days += 1` or `days++`.

Finally, note that this is not the correct way to determine whether a year is a leap year.  See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) for the full algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized `numyears`so it contains an **Indeterminate value** a.k.a Garbage value to begin with.
This Indeterminate value is being used when you do any further operations including `numyears++` and the calculation in `printf()`.

You should initialize it:

```
int numyears = 0;
```

Also, `index` is never used but declared So You can remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, but I'm still getting a number that's way off. It's still printing out 4,201,453 days, when the answer should be 731. I'll make the correction in the original post.

Comment: @user1236785: Same is the case with `days` variable, Do Initialize it.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer before me you should also initialize `days` so

```
int numyears = 0, days = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel so dumb, but I'm still not quite used to how C handles variables. I managed to get the difference in days down to 1095, so there must be another calculation error somewhere..

Answer (score 2):

Your line:

```
while (difference <= endyear) {
```

Should be:

```
while (difference < endyear) {
```

Because if you're going from 2003-2005, you want to go through the loop twice, not 3 times.  (difference = 2003 the first time, 2004 the second, then it should stop).

Comment: And that was the final step! Thanks so much! I'll accept this as an answer, although both other users were very helpful.